# Keycode from a serial PDA keyboard (iPAQ G750)

Tags: embedded, hex, encodings, protocol, byte-code

I have a folding PDA keyboard (model number iPAQ G750). It is using a proprietary serial protocol, I want to adapt it to Bluetooth using a micro controllers. The keyboard sends out a 2-byte keycode every time a key is pressed or released. Some effort of modding the keyboard is documented here: https://www.instructables.com/HP-Compaq-IPAQ-G750-Keyboard-to-USB/

I can't figure out too much pattern from the keycodes, except the most significant bit encodes pressed/released. Can anybody look at the keycodes and find some patterns from it? Is it a keyscan code denoting the rows and columns? Usually keycodes are 1-byte to allow more efficient processing. I can use the 2-byte keycodes with a hashmap but that is inefficient for micro controllers.

Here is the mapping from keycode to the actual keys.

```
void keySetup() {
  keyMapDown[0x16e9] = '1';
  keyMapUp[0x96e9] = '1';
  
  keyMapDown[0x1ee1] = '2';
  keyMapUp[0x9ee1] = '2';
  
  keyMapDown[0x26d9] = '3';
  keyMapUp[0xa6d9] = '3';
  
  keyMapDown[0x25da] = '4';
  keyMapUp[0xa5da] = '4';
  
  keyMapDown[0x2ed1] = '5';
  keyMapUp[0xaed1] = '5';
  
  keyMapDown[0x36c9] = '6';
  keyMapUp[0xb6c9] = '6';
  
  keyMapDown[0x3dc2] = '7';
  keyMapUp[0xbdc2] = '7';
  
  keyMapDown[0x3ec1] = '8';
  keyMapUp[0xbec1] = '8';
  
  keyMapDown[0x46b9] = '9';
  keyMapUp[0xc6b9] = '9';
  
  keyMapDown[0x45ba] = '0';
  keyMapUp[0xc5ba] = '0';

  
  //Letter keys
  keyMapDown[0x1ce3] = 'a';
  keyMapUp[0x9ce3] = 'a';
  
  keyMapDown[0x32cd] = 'b';
  keyMapUp[0xb2cd] = 'b';
  
  keyMapDown[0x21de] = 'c';
  keyMapUp[0xa1de] = 'c';
  
  keyMapDown[0x23dc] = 'd';
  keyMapUp[0xa3dc] = 'd';
  
  keyMapDown[0x24db] = 'e';
  keyMapUp[0xa4db] = 'e';
  
  keyMapDown[0x2bd4] = 'f';
  keyMapUp[0xabd4] = 'f';
  
  keyMapDown[0x34cb] = 'g';
  keyMapUp[0xb4cb] = 'g';
  
  keyMapDown[0x33cc] = 'h';
  keyMapUp[0xb3cc] = 'h';
  
  keyMapDown[0x43bc] = 'i';
  keyMapUp[0xc3bc] = 'i';
  
  keyMapDown[0x3bc4] = 'j';
  keyMapUp[0xbbc4] = 'j';
  
  keyMapDown[0x42bd] = 'k';
  keyMapUp[0xc2bd] = 'k';
  
  keyMapDown[0x4bb4] = 'l';
  keyMapUp[0xcbb4] = 'l';
  
  keyMapDown[0x3ac5] = 'm';
  keyMapUp[0xbac5] = 'm';
  
  keyMapDown[0x31ce] = 'n';
  keyMapUp[0xb1ce] = 'n';
  
  keyMapDown[0x44bb] = 'o';
  keyMapUp[0xc4bb] = 'o';
  
  keyMapDown[0x4db2] = 'p';
  keyMapUp[0xcdb2] = 'p';
  
  keyMapDown[0x15ea] = 'q';
  keyMapUp[0x95ea] = 'q';
  
  keyMapDown[0x2dd2] = 'r';
  keyMapUp[0xadd2] = 'r';
  
  keyMapDown[0x1be4] = 's';
  keyMapUp[0x9be4] = 's';
  
  keyMapDown[0x2cd3] = 't';
  keyMapUp[0xacd3] = 't';
  
  keyMapDown[0x3cc3] = 'u';
  keyMapUp[0xbcc3] = 'u';
  
  keyMapDown[0x2ad5] = 'v';
  keyMapUp[0xaad5] = 'v';
  
  keyMapDown[0x1de2] = 'w';
  keyMapUp[0x9de2] = 'w';
  
  keyMapDown[0x22dd] = 'x';
  keyMapUp[0xa2dd] = 'x';
  
  keyMapDown[0x35ca] = 'y';
  keyMapUp[0xb5ca] = 'y';
  
  keyMapDown[0x1ae5] = 'z';
  keyMapUp[0x9ae5] = 'z';


  //Symbol keys  
  keyMapDown[0xef1] = '`';
  keyMapUp[0x8ef1] = '`';
  
  keyMapDown[0x4eb1] = '-';
  keyMapUp[0xceb1] = '-';
  
  keyMapDown[0x55aa] = '=';
  keyMapUp[0xd5aa] = '=';
  
  keyMapDown[0x4cb3] = ';';
  keyMapUp[0xccb3] = ';';
  
  keyMapDown[0x5da2] = '\'';
  keyMapUp[0xdda2] = '\'';

  // # key but mapping is wrong so has to be changed
  keyMapDown[0x52ad] = 92;
  keyMapUp[0xd2ad] = 92;
  
  keyMapDown[0x41be] = ',';
  keyMapUp[0xc1be] = ',';
  
  keyMapDown[0x49b6] = '.';
  keyMapUp[0xc9b6] = '.';
  
  keyMapDown[0x4ab5] = '/';
  keyMapUp[0xcab5] = '/';

  // \ key but mapping is wrong so has to be changed
  keyMapDown[0x748b] = 49;
  keyMapUp[0xf48b] = 49;

  keyMapDown[0x54ab] = '[';
  keyMapUp[0xd4ab] = '[';

  keyMapDown[0x5ba4] = ']';
  keyMapUp[0xdba4] = ']';


  //Special keys
  keyMapDown[0x718e] = KEY_BACKSPACE;
  keyMapUp[0xf18e] = KEY_BACKSPACE;
  
  keyMapDown[0x5ca3] = ' ';
  keyMapUp[0xdca3] = ' '; 
  
  keyMapDown[0x58a7] = KEY_CAPS_LOCK;
  keyMapUp[0xd8a7] = KEY_CAPS_LOCK;
  
  keyMapDown[0x14eb] = KEY_LEFT_CTRL;
  keyMapUp[0x94eb] = KEY_LEFT_CTRL;
  
  keyMapDown[0x12ed] = KEY_LEFT_SHIFT;
  keyMapUp[0x92ed] = KEY_LEFT_SHIFT;
  
  keyMapDown[0x708f] = KEY_LEFT_ALT;
  keyMapUp[0xf08f] = KEY_LEFT_ALT;
  
  keyMapDown[0x7f8] = KEY_LEFT_GUI;
  keyMapUp[0x87f8] = KEY_LEFT_GUI;
  
  keyMapDown[0x738c] = KEY_RIGHT_CTRL;
  keyMapUp[0xf38c] = KEY_RIGHT_CTRL;
  
  keyMapDown[0x59a6] = KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT;
  keyMapUp[0xd9a6] = KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT;
  
  keyMapDown[0x11ee] = KEY_RIGHT_ALT;
  keyMapUp[0x91ee] = KEY_RIGHT_ALT;
  
  keyMapDown[0x6699] = KEY_DELETE;
  keyMapUp[0xe699] = KEY_DELETE;
  
  keyMapDown[0x5aa5] = KEY_RETURN;
  keyMapUp[0xdaa5] = KEY_RETURN;
  
  keyMapDown[0xdf2] = KEY_TAB;
  keyMapUp[0x8df2] = KEY_TAB;
  
  keyMapDown[0x28d7] = KEY_UP_ARROW;
  keyMapUp[0xa8d7] = KEY_UP_ARROW;
  
  keyMapDown[0x609f] = KEY_DOWN_ARROW;
  keyMapUp[0xe09f] = KEY_DOWN_ARROW;
  
  keyMapDown[0x5ea1] = KEY_LEFT_ARROW;
  keyMapUp[0xdea1] = KEY_LEFT_ARROW;
  
  keyMapDown[0x2fd0] = KEY_RIGHT_ARROW;
  keyMapUp[0xafd0] = KEY_RIGHT_ARROW;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out:

- the most significant bit: 0 is pressed, 1 is released
- Mask the 16-bit with 0b0111111111111111 (ignoring the most significant bit), the first 8 bits and the second 8 bits are inversed, i.e. first_byte XOR second_byte = 0b11111111
- So practically we just need to look at the first byte, the second byte is for error detection, I guess.